# When to use Callbacks and Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, es6-promise

I'm new to NodeJs and to JS actually. I coded my first application using callbacks everywhere and I reached a state where I couldn't handle the number of nested callbacks anymore (callback hell). So I searched for solutions and I read that Promises are one of the best ways to solve this problem. Btw, here's a good explanation for those who are interested: https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-async-best-practices-avoiding-callback-hell-node-js-at-scale/

Therefore, I made a refactoring in the most critical functions using Promises and it works very well. However, I don't know if I should refactor all the application. How do JS developers do nowadays? Do they use Promises everywhere or do they keep using callbacks the most part of the time and use Promises only when there are too many nested callbacks? Is there a best practice for that?

Comment: You should keep your APIs consistent. Using callbacks here but promises there makes it hard to combine calls (e.g. promise chains) and leaves you guessing each time which convention should be used.

Comment: While you are at it, your article also mentions `async/await` which is even easier to maintain and read. Using either callbacks, Promise, Generator (/ coroutines), async/await is upto one's preferences. Async/await has recently become available since Node.js v7.6.0 (without flag) and it has many people excited for ease to use.